# Is my replaceWith code wrong?

Tags: jquery

Is my replaceWith code wrong?

```
if(copyDiv == null)
   copyDiv = origDiv.clone();
else
   $(origDiv).clone().replaceWith(copyDiv);
```

Comment: I am making a copy When the copy is null, when its not null i want to copy "copyDiv" in to "origDiv". Later i modifying OrigDiv. My question is how can I replace origDiv with copyDiv? What I am doing wrong? 

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you cloning something you're trying to replace?  Is this the full context of the javascript?  What about the associated HTML?

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing the rest of your code, it's difficult to say for sure, but it seems that `origDiv` is already a jQuery object.

There's no need to clone it and then replace it with `copyDiv`. Also, it's worth noting that any replacement will happen when `copyDiv != null` (I don't know how often that will be without seeing where you have already defined it...)

Simply running the following should suffice:

```
if(copyDiv == null)
{
   copyDiv = origDiv.clone();
}

origDiv.replaceWith(copyDiv);
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you are trying to do this:

```
if(copyDiv == null) {
    copyDiv = origDiv.clone();
}else {
    $(origDiv).html(copyDiv.html());
}
```